# Laravel 5.3 passing parameter from view to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an online shop, so it has products. I am outputing all the products images and their names and I want when the user clicks on the product to redirect him to a single-product page the problem I have is passing the id of the product to the single-product view.

Here's my code Routing:

```
Route::get('single', [
    "uses" => 'ProductsController@single',
    "as" => 'single'
]);
```

Index.blade.php:

```
<a href="{{ route('single', $product->product_id) }}" class="link-product-add-cart">See product</a>
```

And the controller:

```
public function single($product_id)
{
    $product = Product::where('product_id', $product_id);

    return view('single-product', compact("product"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture segments of the URI within your [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters).

```
Route::get('single/{id}', [
    "uses" => 'ProductsController@single',
    "as" => 'single'
]);
```

Comment: I get
Missing required parameters for [Route: single] [URI: single/{id}]. error

Comment: inside your view pass the parameter like so: `{{ route('single', ['id' => $product->product_id]) }}`

Comment: More about passing paramter inside the route URL go to this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route

Comment: I continue to get the same error
I have this: `<a href="{{ route('single', ['product_id' => $product->product_id]) }}" class="link-product-add-cart">See product</a>`

Comment: rename the route `id` to `product_id`  Route::get('single/{product_id}'...

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your route as given below:

```
Route::get('single/{product_id}', [
    "uses" => 'ProductsController@single',
    "as" => 'single'
]);
```

If you want to pass any parameters to your route then you've to assign placeholders for the parameters, so in your case, the `{product_id}` will be used as the placeholder which will be used to take the parameter from the `URI`, for example: `http://example.com/single/1`. So, you'll receive the `1` as `$product_id` in your single method.

Comment: I get Missing required parameters for [Route: single] [URI: single/{id}]. error

Comment: Is there a `product_id` filed available or it's something else in the products table?

Comment: I have table products and the unique id key is named product_id